# Autoloading with namespaces

Tags: php

My structure:

```
/test/init.php
/test/sub/Info.php
```

init.php:

```
<?php

namespace test;

$namespaces = function($path) {
    //echo $path; = test\sub\Info
    if (preg_match('/\\\\/', $path)) {
        $path = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
    }
    //echo $path; = test\sub\Info
    if (file_exists("{$path}.php")) {
        require_once("{$path}.php");
    }
};

spl_autoload_register($namespaces);

$info = new sub\Info();
```

And Info.php:

```
<?php

namespace test\sub;

class Info
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 123;
    }
}
```

Why this isn't working?

I use Windows, so why DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == \?

EDIT:
Sorry, I updated  my question. I forgot to paste spl_autoload_register on stackoverflow.

Comment: Where do you invoke the autoloader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a relative path, so there are several things that could be wrong... You can see which is the current working directory by doing:

```
echo getcwd();
```

You could also try something like this:

```
$namespaces = function($class) {
    $basepath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $file = $basepath . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . ".php";

    if (!file_exists($file) || !is_readable($file)) {
        return false;
    }

    require_once($file);

    return class_exists($class, false);
};
```

Variable `$basepath` could be also a defined constant, or a variable from a config file...

Answer (score 1):

Your autoloader ideally needs to be defined outside of a namespace, at the top level of the directory structure - the way you've got it set up at the moment, it's trying to include the file `test/sub/Info.php` from within the test directory, rather than from the root (i.e. `test/test/sub/Info.php`, which doesn't exist)

If you remove the namespace prefix `test` from both files (so remove it entirely from `init.php` and just have `namespace sub;` in `sub/Info.php`) then it will work correctly. The other option would be to move the autoloader into a file in the root directory, so that the namespaces again match up with the file-system layout.